# Dativ (von) vs Genitiv(des)

Tags: preposition, usage, dative, genitive

Is there a rule when to use *von*? I know that before countries for example:

Der Präsident von Spanien.

Is it because there is no article before countries? for example Die Schweiz has an article so I would say: Der Präsident der Schweiz.

Before business names (also no article)? Der Schlagzeuger von Coldplay? Der Präsident von Edeka?

Any other examples when to use *von* and not *des/der*?

Comment: "Der Spanische König hieß Juan." oder "Der König Spaniens hieß Juan." oder "Spaniens König hieß Juan." all are correct and interchangeable.

Comment: "Der Schweizer Held heisst Tell." oder "Der Held der Schweiz heisst Tell." are Vorrecht and interchangeable. "Der Schweiz' Held heisst Tell." is just uncommon because of the unpronounceble "z'", else the same as for  the others applies.

Comment: Another valid example: "Der Ukraines verlorenener Teil ist die Krim."

Comment: Autocompletion put "Vorrecht" instead of "correct":. Please excuse.

Comment: It's *der Ukraine*.

Answer (score 3):

There is no rule to use *von*. The genitive works with all names, such as *von* does with the Dative. It's your choice whether you want to use *von* or the genitive (*von* is a bit more colloquial, while the genitive might sound posh in places. Using *von* with a proper name that carries an article, see further down).

> der Präsident der Niederlande
>
> der König von Spanien
>
> Spaniens König
>
> Berlins Regierender Bürgermeister
>
> der Schweizer Bundespräsident
>
> der Bundespräsident der Schweiz

Proper names of geographic entities that are used without article typically get an -s appended in the genitive case. When names that are normally used without article carry one, the -s ending is often omitted:

> die Zentralbank Europas

vs

> die Zentralbank des geeinten Europa(s)

Proper names of geographic locations that only occur in **plural**, e.g. *die Niederlande*, *die Vereinigten Staaten*, **always** carry an article.

While not wrong, using *von* with geographical names that carry an article might sound uncommon, or even clumsy - native speakers will avoid this:

> <s>der Präsident von den Vereinigten Staaten</s>
>
> <s>der Bundespräsident von der Schweiz</s>

Comment: Thanks @torfo! Just to be clear: you can't say: Der Präsident der Spanien and you also can't say Der Präsident von Schweiz, so doesn't it show that it has something to do with the articles? so they are not interchangeable. Also I think Die Schweiz is actually femanine not plural

Comment: There are some names that *need* an article and some that don't, yes. And the genitive looks different in both cases. *der Präsident Spaniens, der Präsident der Schweiz*.

Comment: So you can't use the dative version with Schweiz (z.B), that's what I mean.

Comment: Everything depends on the sort of text you are producing. In a colloquial talk over a number of beers with your friends in the pub you may well say "Der Präsident von den Vereinigten Staaten hat sie nimmer alle". It would not be a very well-formed sentence, but still nobody would complain about your language, and probably even nobody would notice the mistake.  Contrary to that, in a newspaper article you are obliged to say "der Präsident der Vereinigten Staaten" (i.e. pay attention to well-formed and stylistically appropriate sentences).